# Is it possible to avoid a nested loop join when joining over non-overlapping prefixes of a field?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a database of QSO (radio contact) records that I would like to aggregate by station country. The country is derived from a prefix of the station callsign, as defined by the [ITU Prefix List](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ITU_prefix)

Unfortunately, this prefix is of variable length. For instance, everything starting with W is allocated to the US, but most countries are identified by one or several 2-character prefixes. Some require 3-character prefixes, for instance, 3DA to 3DM is Swaziland but 3DN to 3DZ is Fidji.

I can build a table like so:

```
CREATE TABLE country (
    prefix varchar(3) primary key,
    country varchar(10)
);
```

and perform a simple join with the rather ugly expression:

```
SELECT * from qso
INNER JOIN country
ON left(qso.callsign, length(country.prefix)) = country.prefix
```

Understandably, this performs the join using a nested loop. That makes sense, as without the additional knowledge that prefixes in my country table will not overlap, this join could return several countries for a single QSO.

Now, i could use an ugly hack, and insert all explicit 3-character prefixes in my `prefix` table, and use an equality join. This would increase the size of my prefix table 150 times, but naturally allow the use of a Hash or Merge Join.

But, my prefixes do not overlap, and the QSOs are already indexed by callsign, so there is an obvious efficient merge-like algorithm for performing this join.

Is there any way to lead Postgres to the join algorithm i'm thinking of ? Maybe using a fancy index type, or a special match operator ?

Note: The QSO table is something like:

```
CREATE TABLE qso (
    time_on timestamp primary key,
    callsign varchar(10),
    ...
);
CREATE INDEX qso_callsign ON qso(callsign);
```

Comment: what is the qso table structure?

Comment: Added it to the post, but it's probably irrelevant to the question.

Comment: Did you think about breaking the callsign in two parts, prefix and the rest? What are the problems with that? Add that to the question

Comment: Yes, it's not a bad idea, but the full callsign is already used as an identifier all over the place, and there are additional subtleties such as roaming prefixes and station type suffixes. I lied, i'm not directly joining on the callsign, but on a function of it.

Comment: Don't some TU prefixes overlap?  For example, Liechtenstein (HB0, HB3Y, HBL) seems to be a subset of Switzerland (HB).

Comment: I think the Wikipedia entry is wrong, Liechtenstein uses HB0 (and HB0Y for novice licenses), while Switzerland only uses HB9 (for full) and HB3 (for novices) within the HB range. HB3Y is definitely used by Switzerland.

Comment: Sample data would be nice. SQLFiddle.com?

Comment: I suspect you can do more with a composite index on `(prefix_length, prefix)`, but I can't bring myself to mess around with creating the sample data. If you post some I'll have a go.

Comment: If the prefixes, countries, or callsigns are not stable (in time) you'll have a terrible datamodelling nightmare. For instance: what happened to the Yougoslavian prefixes and callsigns, after the split-up ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems one proper way to do this would be to define a custom prefix-matching function with `CREATE OPERATOR`, and mark it as merge-joinable via the `MERGES` clause.  I'll edit this answer when I have tested that this indeed works.

Another may be to use a limited subselect to find the "largest" prefix smaller than the callsign, as defined by the natural collation order -- that might be much more natural.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best bet is to add all three-character prefixes to the `country` table.  I don't see how this would increase it "150 times".  Assuming the codes have 26 upper case characters and 10 numbers, this would at most increase it 36 times.  However, most of the codes probably don't have countries, so the number would be much less -- just the number of 3-character codes actually assigned to countries.

Another alternative would be to do two joins like this:

```
select qso.*, coalesce(c3.whatever, c2.whatever) -- use the c3 version first, then the c2 version
from qso left outer join
     country c2
     ON left(qso.callsign,2) = c2.prefix left outer join
     country c3
     on left(qso.callsign, 3) = c3.prefix;
```

These joins should use an index on the `country` table.  And if you encapsulate it in a view, then other code can just use it.

Comment: well, there are about 300 defined range, while there are 36^3 possible three-letter prefixes, but yes, that was a crude back-of-the-enveloppe estimation. Doing the join in fixed passes of different sizes is a very interesting idea, i have to think more about it